# what @ (at symbol) in square braces on sqlplus shell script mean?

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, sqlplus

I am working on a shell script to work with sqlplus (oracle), in code part below:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

################ Checking tables ###################
TABLES=$(sqlplus -s  ${DBUSER}/${DBPASS}@${DBHOST} <<EOF
...
EOF
)

SuccessTabs=$TABLES

########## Export data from tables to file #########
for TABLE in $TABLES
do
echo "--- Processing $TABLE ---" >> $Log
FILE=$TABLE.csv
TotFiles=$TotFiles$FILE" " -------------------------> (1) Not understand this line ?
sqlplus -s  ${DBUSER}/${DBPASS}@${DBHOST} <<EOF
...
SPOOL $FILE
Select ... FROM $TABLE;
SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF

return=$?
if [ $return != 0 ]
then
SuccessTabs=({$SuccessTabs[@]/$TABLE}) -------------> (2) Not understand this line ?
else
echo "--- $TABLE.csv process success ---" >> $Log
fi
done
echo "--- Process all tables success --- " >> $Log
echo "$SuccessTabs " >> $Log
FinalFile=FINAL_"_"${rundate}_${logtime}".csv"
echo "--- Merge all files into $FinalFile ---" >> $Log
cat $TotFiles > $FinalFile
```

The question is I have two command lines even I know literally what it is used for print out result, but still not understand what its syntax and mechanism.

(1) `TotFiles=$TotFiles$FILE" "` what is double quote with space at the end used for and why syntax like this ?

(2) `SuccessTabs=({$SuccessTabs[@]/$TABLE})` what is `[]`, `@`, `/` combine together used for in this command and why syntax like this, especially for `[@]` , I would like to know what is this ?

Could someone help me to figure out ? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's talk about `[@]` first. In bash you can declare an array like so:

```
declare -a testarray=('box' 'cat' 'dog')
```

You can echo the contents of testarray by doing this:

```
echo ${testarray[@]}
```

Result: `box cat dog`

Now, let's see an interesting behavior:

```
echo ${testarray[@]/dog}
box cat
```

See what happened here? Find dog and replace it with nothing. Check this out:

```
echo ${testarray[@]/dog/pig}
box cat pig
```

That just replaced dog with pig.

So, the answer to your 2nd question is that if `SuccessTabs` array contains the same text as in `$TABLE`, that text is replaced with nothing. The result is assigned back to variable `SuccessTabs`.

---

So what's the `TotFiles=$TotFiles$FILE" "` doing? Taking the same test array example, let's loop through all its values.

```
$ declare -a testarray=('box' 'cat' 'dog')
$ for item in ${testarray[@]}; do
>     testvar=$testvar$item".."
>     echo $testvar
> done
box..
box..cat..
box..cat..dog..
```

So, in the 1st loop, `$testvar` is nothing. `$item` is `box`. `$testvar$item".."` is `box..`. This value is assigned to `testvar` variable.

In the 2nd loop, `$testvar` is `box..`. `$item` is `cat`. `$testvar$item".."` is `box..cat..`. This value is assigned to `testvar` variable.

In the 3rd loop, `$testvar` is `box..cat..`. `$item` is `dog`. `$testvar$item".."` is `box..cat..dog..`. This value is assigned to `testvar` variable.

Similarly, if TABLES is a list/array containing `box cat dog`, $FILE will be box.csv, cat.csv and dog.csv during each iteration of TABLES. `TotFiles=$TotFiles$FILE" "` will become `box.csv cat.csv dog.csv`.

See more examples in two places:

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html
- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html

My examples above may have inaccuracies. The goal was to give you an example of how to get the information you were looking for.

Comment: Nice. Regarding the first part of you answer, please note that the op has misplaced the opening brace as in `{$SuccessTabs[@]/$TABLE}` .

Comment: @zedfoxus, fabulous answer, awesome example and helpful link, I fully understand the code behavior after reading your answer, especially the elegant example with detail analysis.

Answer (score 0):

```
TotFiles=$TotFiles$FILE" "
```

appends to `TotFiles`, the contents of `FILE` and a space( that is why you have `" "`) to existing `TotFiles`. I would suggest writing this as

```
TotFiles="${TotFiles}${file} "  # It's not suggested to use UpperCase letters for user variables
```

Regarding

```
SuccessTabs=({$SuccessTabs[@]/$TABLE})
```

It doesn't make much sense to me unless you've declared `SuccessTabs` as an array. Note that if you have

```
declare -a var=( array...stuff )
var=( ${var[@]/STUFF_TO_OMIT} ) #omits the `STUFF_TO_OMIT` from the array, ie it gives you everything except `STUFF_TO_OMIT`
```

If that is what you intended to do then you need to change

```
SuccessTabs=({$SuccessTabs[@]/$TABLE})
```

to

```
SuccessTabs=( ${SuccessTabs[@]/$TABLE} ) # See how curly brackets are placed, again not a good idea using uppercase variables !
```

Comment: also thank you for your post and comment, give me some valuable hint.